# pagination script in jquery for table pagination

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

HI all

I want to paginate with table i.e in one page have contain 5 data table, but i can not find the useful  document in django template so now i want to implement it with jquery. sow how can i  it implement???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some tutorials about applying pagination with jquery.

<strike>[Complete script for sorting and paging](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/jquery/jquery-sorting-and-paging-code.html)</strike>

[Complete tutorial on pagination with jquery](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/jquery/jquery-pagination.html)

EDIT: the above links 404. Here are new tutorials:

[jPaginate (jQuery Plugin)](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/17/jpaginate-a-fancy-jquery-pagination-plugin/)

[Making jQuery Pagination System](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-a-jquery-pagination-system/)

Comment: hi, I have need more documentation

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function . Its taken from https://convertintowordpress.com/simple-jquery-table-pagination-code/

```
function pagination(){
    var req_num_row=10;
    var $tr=jQuery('tbody tr');
    var total_num_row=$tr.length;
    var num_pages=0;
    if(total_num_row % req_num_row ==0){
        num_pages=total_num_row / req_num_row;
    }
    if(total_num_row % req_num_row >=1){
        num_pages=total_num_row / req_num_row;
        num_pages++;
        num_pages=Math.floor(num_pages++);
    }
    for(var i=1; i<=num_pages; i++){
        jQuery('#pagination').append("<a href='#' class='btn'>"+i+"</a>");
    }
    $tr.each(function(i){
        jQuery(this).hide();
        if(i+1 <= req_num_row){
            $tr.eq(i).show();
        }

    });
    jQuery('#pagination a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $tr.hide();
        var page=jQuery(this).text();
        var temp=page-1;
        var start=temp*req_num_row;
        //alert(start);

        for(var i=0; i< req_num_row; i++){

            $tr.eq(start+i).show();

        }
    });
}
```