# Printing web pages in an order

Tags: php, javascript, printing

I've a php file which'll run a SQL script and fetch information about users.

Some user's information may span 2 or 3 pages while some might end in just 1.

I want to print the **beginning of ever user's report in a new page**. All these process has to be automated because there are some **400** users, and the client can't select **page layout** for every user or print them individually.

How can i achieve this? using PHP or Javascript?
Is there any library to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was a little confusing, but now I *think* you're talking about doing page breaks in a [print.css](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/)?  If so you can use: [page-break-before and page-break-after](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-before) in your CSS.

So using CSS you would do something like:

```
div.pagecontainer { page-break-after:always; }
```

Where your page was contained in:

```
<div class="pagecontainer">page content here</div>
```

If you're just trying to figure out [pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination_%28web%29).   Take a look at [this php solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465999/php-pagination-class).

You can also do completely client side pagination as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672609/how-to-create-pagination-like-stackoverflow) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117721/pagination-script-in-jquery-for-table-pagination).

Comment: oh!  Perhaps you're looking for the css to do a page break?  Take a look at page-break-after: always;